# How to update Google Chrome Developer Tools local storage view?

Tags: local-storage, google-chrome-devtools

I have the Chrome Dev Tools View opened. I choose Application > Storage > Local Storage. Now I see the current localstorage. Fine.

Whenever I reload or have a "hot code push" that updates my site, the localstorage dissappears. I have to close and reopen dev tools, then it is updated.

Is there a button "reload local storage" or something? Or a way to keep it always up to date?

Comment: That's not a programming question I guess...

Comment: there is a tag google-chrome-devtools, it means he can ask question related to that. I think its a valid question even its not a programming question

Comment: Sounds like https://crbug.com/701413

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fails as you described on my Mac running Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit).  Appears to be fixed after updating to Version 59.0.3071.109 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Answer (score 1):

When I run the [Web Storage](https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/web-storage/) example in [Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) (Chrome 59) it looks fixed. The key-values update right as I change them.

Unless you're still seeing the problem when you run the site in Canary, then you've just got to wait a couple months until the changes land in Chrome Stable.

Comment: I meant the other way around: so updating the website does not update the localstorage for me (even in Canary).

Comment: Local Storage doesn't get updated even when you run the page I provided on Canary, is that correct? Sounds like a bug. What OS are you using?

Comment: I use Mac Os. And yes, it sounds like the bug wOxxOm mentioned in the comments above on my question.

Comment: @obiwahn I just updated Canary, and it works there! Version 59.0.3069.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit)